# intellij idea cannot import local jars in local repository which I just installed by maven install

Tags: java, maven

I am new to intellij idea and I was blocked in the bulid-process. I get two springcloud based projects and I have installed the so called 'scp-accesscontrol-component-client' in one workplace and I have found the installed jar in local repository.[image: cannot find the jar] But the other project dependency cannot import the jar from local repository but download from the remote repository and it cannot find the jar for I haven't deploy into the remote reposite. How to set IDEA to aotu-import bulit-jars from the  local repository?thanks!
[image: jars I have installed in local repository][image: jars found in local repository]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using maven, you can add it to the pom.xml file as a dependency. Then IDE will get the jar automatically when running the maven command.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abccompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-app</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Surely the dependency has been added ,but ide still cannot get the jar automatically. It seems that it goes to the remote repository for a download and cannot find one. the problem is that I have installed the needed jars successfully in local repository but the ide cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar issue, try next:
in intellij idea go to Project Structure -> under Project Settings select Libraries -> Add -> select .jar file you need to import